# Prevent sharing of unmounted drives

Tags: mount, samba

I have a file server set up to share an external drive over samba and netatalk (AFP). I have an fstab entry to automatically mount the drive at `/mnt/external`, which then gets shared automatically by the various daemons.

The problem is if the drive doesn't mount properly (e.g. if I forgot to turn it on, or if I took it to work that day). In this case the mountpoint gets shared without the corresponding drive attached, resulting in various meta files getting written to my mount point rather than a clean failure. This prevents the drive from mounting properly the next time I attach it (non-empty directory), and could lead to data loss if someone used the share in the mean time.

Is there any way to cause the shares to fail in the case that the drive is unmounted?

Comment: I would mount the disk in a script called by `/etc/rc.local` (and by hand afterward) so that I can create the directory on mount and remove it on umount. That should lead to a clean failure of the sharing daemons...

Comment: Quantum7: If the above comment doesn't mean anything to you, leave a comment below...  @RMano: you want to do the honours if OP replies?

Comment: Thats a good idea, Rmano. If you flesh it out into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your original mount folder attributes to make it `immutable`:

```
chattr +i /mnt/external
```

The folder is now locked and any operation on it is forbidden (you can unlock it using `-i`).
However `mount` or `fstab` still work properly.

---

*Make sure the drive is not mounted before running `chattr`. If you get the error `"Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags"`, maybe your are working on a filesystem that doesn't support attributes on folders. In fact some Linux distributions mount the main partition using `overlayfs` filesystem instead of `ext`. So you have to mount it manually elsewhere in order to get `chattr` working on folders (i.e. `mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/temp` then `chattr +i /mnt/temp/root/mnt/external`).*

Comment: An answer after 6 years! There should be a badge for that! This would have been better than what I ended up going with, which was to add a single top-level directory inside the mount (e.g. /mnt/external/work/). As long as I used that path consistently I would get errors writing files rather than silent file creations.

Comment: @Quantum7 Thanks! ;) Well only the few people trying to make a time machine themselves get to your question I guess. Your solution was great as well, hadn't thought about it.